# Force Joomla JRoute to use the menu item

Tags: php, joomla, routes, joomla2.5, url-routing

I'm building a component for Joomla! 2.5 and inside I'm using `JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_myapp&view=cpanel')` to build all my links. This works, BUT it produces links which look like that:

```
/component/myapp/cpanel.html
```

In the menu however I have defined that `index.php?option=com_myapp&view=cpanel` has an alias of "myapp" so the link should rather be

```
/myapp/cpanel.html
```

The component is accessible via this path. If I do that, also all links generated inside will have the `/myapp` prefix. But for use in a template (special login link) and if the user stumbles upon `/component/myapp`.... I still want all links to go to `/myapp` prefix.

How can I force JRoute to use this menu item entry by itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//look if there is a menu item set for myapp. if yes, we use that one to redirect
$db  = JFactory::getDBO();
$defaultRedirect = 'index.php?option=com_myapp&view=cpanel';
$db->setQuery('SELECT `id` FROM #__menu WHERE `link` LIKE '. $db->Quote($defaultRedirect) .' LIMIT 1' );
$itemId = ($db->getErrorNum())? 0 : intval($db->loadResult());
if($itemId){
    $rpath = JRequest::getString('return', base64_encode(JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid='.$itemId)));
}else{
    $rpath = JRequest::getString('return', base64_encode(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_myapp&view=cpanel')));
}
```

Beware: This is NOT language-safe. It takes the first menu entry found in the db. If you setup different menu aliases for different languages you have to check for the right language in the SQL query, too.

Comment: You should add " AND `published` = 1 " to your query, otherwise your query will lead to errors with unpublished / truncated items.

Answer (score 3):

Because I struggled a lot with this issue, here's a quick function I did that will try to find the link based on a menu item. It's mainly based on other answers.

This has only been tested on Joomla 3.5. JRequest is deprecated, so $app->input is used instead. This might be done better, but at least it works for the use I have of it. Hopes it can help other people too !

```
public static function getRouteMenu($default_url) {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $jinput = $app->input;

    $db->setQuery('SELECT `id` FROM #__menu WHERE `link` LIKE '. $db->Quote($default_url) .' AND `published` = 1 LIMIT 1' );
    $itemId = $db->loadResult();
    if($itemId) {
        $route = $jinput->getString('return', JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid='.$itemId));
        $route = str_replace('index.php/', '', $route);
    } else {
        $route = $jinput->getString('return', JRoute::_($default_url));
    }

    return $route;
}
```

The parameter requires a not rewrited link such as : `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10`. Check your database if you need to be sure about how to build up this link.

Answer (score 0):

You ideally need to set a router as part of your component.  The menu manager will override the component/myapp bit, but what comes after that will be determined by what is in the router.php file.

http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

If, however, you simply need to create a link to a specific menu item, then you can always just add an Itemid to your parameter

```
JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid=12')
```

will point to any menu item with the id 12, so if that is your menu item ID for your com_myapp component, it will create the menu version of the link to that page.

edit:

You could technically assign the same component to two menu items, so I don't believe that handling the beginning of the URL is default behaviour when you link to a component outside of a menu item without giving the link an itemid.  Joomla say (on creating a link for JRoute)...

> "Notice that it is possible to leave out the parameters option and
>   Itemid. option defaults to the name of the component currently being
>   executed, and Itemid defaults to the current menu item's ID."

ie, call it from your homepage (or any page outside of one set to use your component) without an itemid or option and it is likely to think you are in com_content and with the homepage menu item.

If you want to link to the component outside of a menu item but without hard-coding an itemid, then one way would be to add a Menuitem field type to the config options of the module or template where you are linking from, and then add the itemid it generates to your link.

You could also use JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu() to find which menu item is linking to your component.  Not had chance to test this - but using that could also mean that you can set an itemid parameter in your router.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a router.php in my component and this part is working fine. The problem is: when I set up another Joomla with this component, the menu item will have a different id. Normally (if I understand the core router.php correctly) Joomla should take care to assign a sef route over the correct menu item to my component.

Comment: Joomla uses the reverse lookup to find potential matching menu items and it basically doesn't do much for you if you are not using categories. So you need to write some custom handling for that. You might need to clone the sef plugin and add your own handling.

Comment: Thanks you both for your input. There seems indeed to exist no way to automatically detect the corresponding menu item. Now I just use the code from my answer.